# IE8 fails to download file from WCF - doesn't recognize filename

Tags: asp.net, wcf, internet-explorer-8, download

I have WCF REST Service whos purpose is to serve files on request.

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Clear();
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileNameWithExtension);
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = contentType;
return new MemoryStream(file.Data);
```

Downloading this works on all browsers but IE8 - Whenever I click the download link it opens a new tab and closes itself. I managed to discover that while for example Chrome is able to recognize the file name properly, IE8 does not see any filename - just like it was ignoring the filename from header. Does anybody have any clue how to approach this ?

edit* I found that if I extract the URL from the link and put it in the address bar of IE8 manually it fails to download on the first try, but goes right ahead on second try. If I see what's happening in Fiddler I find that the first try I see the following header:

```
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=rhyk5nxw3fmrkjonsjknntuw; path=/; HttpOnly
```

The same header is not there when I try to download it the second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I had set the cache control to no-cache, if I comment out the following procedure from my WCF code IE8 handles my files just fine. Weird.

> //HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control",
>   "no-cache"); //HttpContext.Current.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
>   //HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);